# Notifications are not being displayed on Some Android mobiles

Tags: android, notifications, cyanogenmod

In my app I am receiving notifications and I can able to see them in logs. But on some mobiles they are not being displayed. Ex : One plus A0001 (Android 5.1.1 API22).I have read other stackoverflow questions and ensured that all required methods are there.After some exploration I came to know that Cyanogenmod might be the reason for this.But in that case How other apps notifications are displayed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
            .setContentText("Subject")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(6578, n);
}
```

Above code working on all other mobiles.

Comment: Try to use `NotificationCompat`. Give it a shot.

Comment: @Wizard Already tried that one. But no use

Answer (score 0):

Check the notification permissions of your app. Which control by your phone. Maybe in Settings or an pre-installed app.
Especially in China, many phones pre-installed an app called "权限管家" to control third-party app's permissions. Such as show notification in notification bar,  connect to internet while running background or when screen is locked.

Comment: I Checked those settings @Oscar Zhang